# Insert Content In Between Post Feed

Tags: posts, get-posts

I am a bit lost and looking for guidance. I have a homepage that lists blog posts. However after every 3rd post (we'll call this the "Main Feed") I want to add a section in between that looks different and calls a specific category. After that section I want the "Main Feed" to continue.

I've only ever had to call one section at a time and really looking for some guidance. I appreciate the help greatly!

**Main Feed**

```
<?php query_posts('cat=-20'); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
    <div>
      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
      <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </div>


<?php endwhile; ?>  
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

**This Should Interrupt Main Feed Once Every 3 Posts**

```
<?php query_posts(''cat=3&posts_per_page=2''); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
    <div>
      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
      <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </div>


<?php endwhile; ?>  
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

**This Should Interrupt Main Feed Once Every 3 Posts**

```
<?php query_posts(''cat=4&posts_per_page=2''); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
    <div>
      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
      <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </div>


<?php endwhile; ?>  
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I'd like this repeating pattern where specific categories are inserted throughout the main feed every 3 posts.

Comment: show the code that displays your posts on the homepage

Comment: Sure thing, I've gone ahead and added the code with additional explanation, hope that helps. Thanks!

Comment: Related: [It's not a good idea to use `query_posts()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts).

Comment: ...Though on second reading, I note you're using `wp_reset_query()`, which is good practice if you insist on using `query_posts()`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found old pieces of code and joined it with yours. It could be more elegant, but you have the idea.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'category__not_in' => array( 20 ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$posts = $query->posts;
wp_reset_postdata();

$post_counter = 1;

// secondary posts' categories (ids)
$sec_categories = [2, 14, 56, 234];
$cat_counter = 0;


foreach( $posts as $post ) {
    echo '<h1>' . $post->post_title . '</h1>';
    echo '<p>' . $post->post_excerpt . '</p>';

    // after each 3rd post goes (two) secondary
    if( $post_counter % 3 == 0 ) {
        query_posts( 'cat=' . $sec_categories[$cat_counter] . '&posts_per_page=2' );
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            echo '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
            echo '<p>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>';
        }

        wp_reset_query();

        $cat_counter++;
    }

    $post_counter++;
}
```

You have to think out how to choose categories for secondary posts